# Como utilizar corretamente o Async/Await Asp .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

Estou utilizando requisições assíncronas em várias partes do projeto, mas surgiu uma dúvida pois sei que para um método ser assíncrono é necessário o mesmo ser **async** e ter um **await**.

Porém temos alguns métodos no Service que é async e possui várias chamadas await para o Repository, ficando como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
        var url1 = await GetUrlFromBaseAsync(1);
        var url2 = await GetUrlFromBaseAsync(2);
        var url3 = await GetUrlFromBaseAsync(3);
        var file1 = await GetFileBlobStorageAsync(url1);
        var file2 = await GetFileBlobStorageAsync(url2);
        var file3 = await GetFileBlobStorageAsync(url3);

        //outras chamadas...
        Send(file1,file2,file3);
    }
```

Ao debugar parece que cada uma dessas chamadas **await** são chamadas somente quando outra termina e não de forma sincronizada.

Sei que tem recursos que realmente devem ser aguardados para poder continuar, mas eu esperava que fosse buscadas as URLs ao mesmo tempo ou pelo menos a busca pelos arquivos no blobStorage.

Alguém poderia indicar se usando dessa forma o recurso de async não está sendo bem aproveitado?

Comment: O funcionamento está correto, quando usamos o async/awat o compilador gera um estado de espera em segundo plano. Ou seja, isso é feito de forma assíncrona, seu programa fica aguardando a tarefa finalizar. Isso faz com que o fluxo do programa não fique bloqueado.

Comment: Mas existe alguma forma de deixar isso de forma sincronizada?

Answer (score 1):

Um detalhe importante a ser notado é que uma operação assíncrona é diferente de uma operação paralela. A utilização de async/await dessa forma permite a execução assíncrona, o que permite com que você inicie uma execução e tenha um callback (a Task do C#) para poder agir sobre o retorno, quando o mesmo estiver pronto.

No seu caso, ao colocar o **await** em cada chamada, você está explicitamente dizendo que quer esperar pelo resultado da operação antes de continuar a execução do seu método. Isso é uma forma válida de uso de async/await, mas não é a que você está querendo pela sua pergunta.

Um exemplo de implementação dos seus métodos só pra poder ilustrar o que ocorre:

```cs
        private async Task<string> GetUrlFromBaseAsync(int i)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss}: Iniciando GetUrlFromBaseAsync - {i}");

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

            Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss}: Finalizando GetUrlFromBaseAsync - {i}");

            return $"https://www.site{i}.com.br";
        }

        private async Task<string> GetFileBlobStorageAsync(string url)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss}: Iniciando GetFileBlobStorageAsync - {url}");

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

            Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss}: Finalizando GetFileBlobStorageAsync - {url}");

            return string.Empty;
        }
```

Então se você executar da forma como colocou na pergunta, ele deve mostrar no output uma execução sequencial, em que cada um esperou seu fim pra começar a executar o próximo:

```
21:20:47: Iniciando GetUrlFromBaseAsync - 1
21:20:49: Finalizando GetUrlFromBaseAsync - 1
21:20:49: Iniciando GetUrlFromBaseAsync - 2
21:20:51: Finalizando GetUrlFromBaseAsync - 2
21:20:51: Iniciando GetUrlFromBaseAsync - 3
21:20:53: Finalizando GetUrlFromBaseAsync - 3
21:20:53: Iniciando GetFileBlobStorageAsync - https://www.site1.com.br
21:20:58: Finalizando GetFileBlobStorageAsync - https://www.site1.com.br
21:20:58: Iniciando GetFileBlobStorageAsync - https://www.site2.com.br
21:21:03: Finalizando GetFileBlobStorageAsync - https://www.site2.com.br
21:21:03: Iniciando GetFileBlobStorageAsync - https://www.site3.com.br
21:21:08: Finalizando GetFileBlobStorageAsync - https://www.site3.com.br
```

Vou te dar alguns exemplos de maneiras simples de poder executar esses métodos sem esperar, mas não vou incluir loops e afins pra facilitar o exemplo, vou manter as chamadas semelhantes ao que você colocou.

Uma forma é essa:

```cs
            var taskUrl1 = GetUrlFromBaseAsync(1);
            var taskUrl2 = GetUrlFromBaseAsync(2);
            var taskUrl3 = GetUrlFromBaseAsync(3);

            await Task.WhenAll(taskUrl1, taskUrl2, taskUrl3);

            var taskFile1 = GetFileBlobStorageAsync(taskUrl1.Result);
            var taskFile2 = GetFileBlobStorageAsync(taskUrl2.Result);
            var taskFile3 = GetFileBlobStorageAsync(taskUrl3.Result);

            await Task.WhenAll(taskFile1, taskFile2, taskFile3);

            //outras chamadas...
            Send(taskFile1.Result, taskFile2.Result, taskFile3.Result);
```

Com o **Task.WhenAll()**, você especifica que quer esperar pela execução de várias **Task**s antes de continuar para o próximo passo. O output ficou assim:

```
21:27:27: Iniciando GetUrlFromBaseAsync - 1
21:27:27: Iniciando GetUrlFromBaseAsync - 2
21:27:27: Iniciando GetUrlFromBaseAsync - 3
21:27:29: Finalizando GetUrlFromBaseAsync - 1
21:27:29: Finalizando GetUrlFromBaseAsync - 3
21:27:29: Finalizando GetUrlFromBaseAsync - 2
21:27:29: Iniciando GetFileBlobStorageAsync - https://www.site1.com.br
21:27:29: Iniciando GetFileBlobStorageAsync - https://www.site2.com.br
21:27:29: Iniciando GetFileBlobStorageAsync - https://www.site3.com.br
21:27:34: Finalizando GetFileBlobStorageAsync - https://www.site1.com.br
21:27:34: Finalizando GetFileBlobStorageAsync - https://www.site2.com.br
21:27:34: Finalizando GetFileBlobStorageAsync - https://www.site3.com.br
```

Outra possibilidade, já que você tem no seu exemplo um método usando o retorno do outro, é de executar os dois métodos do mesmo índice na mesma **Task**:

```cs
            var task1 = Task<string>.Run(async () => 
            {
                var url = await GetUrlFromBaseAsync(1);
                return await GetFileBlobStorageAsync(url);
            });

            var task2 = Task<string>.Run(async () =>
            {
                var url = await GetUrlFromBaseAsync(2);
                return await GetFileBlobStorageAsync(url);
            });

            var task3 = Task<string>.Run(async () =>
            {
                var url = await GetUrlFromBaseAsync(3);
                return await GetFileBlobStorageAsync(url);
            });

            await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);

            Send(task1.Result, task2.Result, task3.Result);
```

O output foi muito parecido:

```
21:35:34: Iniciando GetUrlFromBaseAsync - 1
21:35:34: Iniciando GetUrlFromBaseAsync - 2
21:35:34: Iniciando GetUrlFromBaseAsync - 3
21:35:36: Finalizando GetUrlFromBaseAsync - 2
21:35:36: Finalizando GetUrlFromBaseAsync - 1
21:35:36: Finalizando GetUrlFromBaseAsync - 3
21:35:36: Iniciando GetFileBlobStorageAsync - https://www.site1.com.br
21:35:36: Iniciando GetFileBlobStorageAsync - https://www.site3.com.br
21:35:36: Iniciando GetFileBlobStorageAsync - https://www.site2.com.br
21:35:41: Finalizando GetFileBlobStorageAsync - https://www.site2.com.br
21:35:41: Finalizando GetFileBlobStorageAsync - https://www.site3.com.br
21:35:41: Finalizando GetFileBlobStorageAsync - https://www.site1.com.br
```